# Script isn't sending login information correctly

Tags: php, send

I'v just began coding my own script about an hour ago and I'v come across an error that I'm unsure how to fix, It appears that everything is parsing correctly except the username, for some reason when I execute my PHP table create script it's not parsing the username from config.php instead it's executing the script with no username.

I'v put the code though phpcodechecker.com/ and it's given me nothing, not even any warnings, it has me really quite confused, the code looks fine to me but I am quite novice at this so I'v probably missed something HUGE, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Why isn't this code parsing the username through to createtable.php when it attempts to connect??

Code snippets in question;
The way stack formats code blocks confuses the hell out of me so I'll just use pastebin

[config.php](http://pastebin.com/vs4bMUVM)

[createtable.php](http://pastebin.com/3yuthTzk)

Comment: If you're connecting in config.php why are you reconnecting in createtable.php?

Comment: You made a very good point, removed that but it's still outputting
   Unable to select the defined database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'testdb' 
  which tells me it's still failing to send the username root through to the database, I don't understand why

Comment: Take a look at Fabio's answer, it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` api in `config.php` which end up with no connection at all

```
mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)

mysql_select_db($db_database)
```

To extabilish a correct connectio to database with mysqli (wich is obviously better to use since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated) do something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
```

You can check [documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

I would like to add that you can use connection from `config.php` in any other scripts simply requiring it.

```
require('config.php');
```

so your `creatables.php` will look like this

```
require("config.php");

$sql="CREATE TABLE quoter (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    quote text NOT NULL,
    quoteby CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PIMARY KEY (id)
    )";

if (mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql))
{
    echo "Table 'quoter' was created sucessfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Error creating table 'quoter': ".mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

and your `config.php`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
}
```

I would like you to note that `$mysqli` is the parameter wich handle connection so you need to pass this one while executing operations in your database, eg

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
           //^here it is
```

Comment: Thank you Fabio, your post was very informative and the source/documentation was very much appreciated, after reading through that I'm going to restart the entire config.php in mysqli, Is there any major issue with the createtable.php file you can see that will conflict with the mysqli in config.php?

Comment: @BenF i've updated my answer to let you understand, please check it

Comment: Thanks again Fabio, I went through the referencing for everything you posted to learn it properly and made a few small changes but essentially you got it working for me :) I was actually considering switching it all back to MySQL but with your help and references MySQLi isn't so daunting.

Comment: @BenF You are welcome. I would suggest to learn about `prepared statements` as next step, it will help you to properly deal with mysql database in any situation.

Comment: success was short lived, for some reason it's saying I'v not got a database selected even though I'v clearly told it to select testdb http://pastebin.com/B3UXrmxy